# Sitecore rich text editor auto-save

Tags: sitecore, rich-text-editor, autosave

The content editors have a constant gripe about losing their work after they've been working on an article for over half an hour. This is a .NET session timeout issue but I do not want to modify that value.

I am looking for an auto-save functionality in Sitecore RTE. There is a blog post by Ivan from Sitecore regarding this - http://sitecoregadgets.blogspot.com/2011/11/rich-text-auto-save.html - where he offered a solution. I want to know if anyone has used this solution and is satisfied with it. Were there any errors, bugs or challenges once this was implemented and how they were overcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore also suggested the same link - http://sitecoregadgets.blogspot.com/2011/11/rich-text-auto-save.html

Comment: Yep, came through on their official RSS feed, I'd be interested to see how well it works, not used it myself.

Comment: Seems the link to package is no more valid. Does anyone still have this package?